# TeamViewer install borked, can't seem to fix

Tags: package-management, xubuntu, 18.10, teamviewer, qt5

Xubuntu 18.10

So the other day I went to run TeamViewer and found it was gone. So I tried to re-install it and this happens:

```
$ sudo apt install teamviewer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 teamviewer : Depends: libqt5qml5 (>= 5.5) but it is not going to be installed or
                       qt56-teamviewer but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqt5quick5 (>= 5.5) but it is not going to be installed or
                       qt56-teamviewer but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqt5webkit5 (>= 5.5) but it is not going to be installed or
                       qt56-teamviewer but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: qml-module-qtquick2 (>= 5.5) but it is not going to be installed or
                       qt56-teamviewer but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: qml-module-qtquick-controls (>= 5.5) but it is not going to be installed or
                       qt56-teamviewer but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: qml-module-qtquick-dialogs (>= 5.5) but it is not going to be installed or
                       qt56-teamviewer but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: qml-module-qtquick-window2 (>= 5.5) but it is not going to be installed or
                       qt56-teamviewer but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: qml-module-qtquick-layouts (>= 5.5) but it is not going to be installed or
                       qt56-teamviewer but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've tried a few things:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

I've also tried Synaptic to install qt56-teamviewer, but that fails too and just says it's "broken".

I suspect a non-standard PPA repository, but any useful way to determine which one so I just fix this problem without causing other problems (such as blowing away the entire `sources.list` and replacing with default)? I noticed a lot of the sources have `bionic` in them even though I'm on `cosmic`. Should I change all references to `bionic` to `cosmic` instead?

-----------edits below---------

```
    $ apt-cache policy qt56-teamviewer libqt5qml5 teamviewer
qt56-teamviewer:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.6.3.0
  Version table:
     5.6.3.0 500
        500 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
libqt5qml5:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.9.5-0ubuntu1.1
  Version table:
     5.9.5-0ubuntu1.1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     5.9.5-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
teamviewer:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 14.2.2558
  Version table:
     14.2.2558 500
        500 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
     14.1.18533 500
        500 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     14.1.9025 500
        500 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
     14.1.3399 500
        500 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
     14.0.14470 500
        500 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
     13.2.26559 500
        500 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
     13.2.13582 500
        500 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: I would check your sources; I picked the first and it's there and its 5.11 > 5.5 (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libqt5qml5&searchon=names&suite=cosmic&section=all), so check your mirror (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors) to ensure it's correct & up-to-date, if needs be change to another one, or if you don't think it's this, `apt-cache policy libqt5qml5` please.

Comment: Also, don't forget to run `sudo apt update` and then, `sudo apt full-upgrade` and then run, `sudo apt install --reinstall qt56-teamviewer`

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy qt56-teamviewer libqt5qml5 teamviewer` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert done. Requested info added to OP

Comment: @mchid

Ran those. Ends with:

`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 qt56-teamviewer : Depends: libqt5webkit5 (>= 5.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.'

Comment: If you really run 18.10, then you should have 18.10 (*cosmic*) everywhere in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. And not 18.04 (*bionic*) Please double check this.

Comment: @N0rbert `$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.10
Release: 18.10
Codename: cosmic`
Should I edit all the bionic references in sources to cosmic?

Comment: Yes, you should. And run `sudo apt dist-upgrade` to get all new dependencies.

Comment: @N0rbert that did it. All good now and Teamviewer is working. Thanks!